# CMYK muted colors question

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Was told if you want to send your design to the print shop for mass printing, best set up your .ai for CMYK. But CMYK have muted colors, if i want to select a specific color (see below). Can CMYK to this? or want would you guys do, if you are facing this issue? [image: 1.jpg]

Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You have too high chroma blue for CMYK. RGB blue which translates to CMYK acceptably should have saturation and brightness about 70% of max or less, exact limits depend on the used paper and print process.

Because it seems to have only blue and white, there surely exists a way to print it as is with a spot color. Consult your printer. You can agree which exact color number will be used.

As Illustrator user you have a tool for predicting the printing result. Learn how to use proof colors and get the needed color settings from your printer. Color calibrated monitor helps to get results which are accurate enough.